# Retrieve Dynamic dropdown select in React

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-redux, frontend, visual-web-developer

Not able to fetch dynamic array in react

```
<div className="input-field col s12">
            <select id='department' required={true} aria-required={true}   onChange={this.handleChange}>
               
          
                {this.state.departmentData.map((dep) =>(
                   <option  key={dep.id} value={dep.id}>{dep.department_name}</option>
                ))}
            </select>
            <label>Department </label>
          </div>
```

Comment: Please add the complete code of the component and maybe someone might be able to help.